# Does import __foo__ import from the __init__ file of the foo package?

Tags: python, package, python-import

I've been reading some code that used the following import statement:

```
import __ompc__
```

When I tried to grep to find just what was being imported, all I found was:

```
me@Bedrock1:~/Projects/PythonProjects/ompc$ grep -r "__ompc__" ./*
./build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/ompclib/m_compile.py:import __ompc__
./build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/ompclib/m_compile.py:        codeobject =    __ompc__.compile(codestring, dfile or file,'exec')
./build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/ompclib/m_compile.py:import __ompc__
./build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/ompclib/m_compile.py:        codeobject =    __ompc__.compile(codestring, dfile or file,'exec')
Binary file ./build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/ompclib/m_compile.pyc matches
./ompclib/m_compile.py:import __ompc__
./ompclib/m_compile.py:        codeobject = __ompc__.compile(codestring, dfile or file,'exec')
```

Since `__ompc__` was used to find a method named '`compile`', I did a recursive grep on that. What I found was the `__init__.py` file in the `./ompc/ompc` directory had a compile method.

Is this what

```
import __ompc__
```

gives access to?  Or is there still something going on here that I don't understand?

Comment: It is not clear to me yet what `ompc` *does*, but the behaviour is very much non-standard.

Comment: @MartijnPieters ompc is a package that attempts to translate Matlab code into code runnable by Python.

Comment: I know what the package *is*, just not what it does to make `import __ompc__` work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot actually make `ompclib/m_compile.py` *work*. `ompc/m_compile.py` is *almost* the same file, but is actually used by the `ompc` codebase.

My conclusion is that that file and probably the whole `ompclib` *directory* is a left-over from an earlier development stage and the author simply has forgotten to clean it up.

The `import __ompc__` import is otherwise nothing more but a broken import. It does not magically transform into importing the `ompc` package. `ompc/m_compile.py` does work, and uses `import ompc` instead.

Comment: Thanks ... I couldn't get them to run either, but couldn't figure out why they were there